# Forwarding to top level domain from www

Tags: url, redirect, namespaces, dns, forwarding

I want to redirect all traffic from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com, even when there is a specific path (like www.mydomain.com/article)

Can I do this through my domain registrar or does it have to be done on the server?

Comment: Look into URL re-writing, it depends on what web server you use..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with simple url rewriting :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

(on apache)

Comment: It depends on your registar, most I know of do not offer more than basic 301 redirection in their admin panel.